# Trade-offs between Job Queue vs. Drupal Queue

Tags: 7, queue

Anyone familiar with both [Job Queue](http://drupal.org/project/job_queue) and [Drupal Queue](http://drupal.org/project/drupal_queue) enough to offer an idea of the tradeoffs between the two?

In case it makes a difference, the site I'm working on uses Drupal 6. The queue I'll be creating will check a batch of user accounts with a REST API, to verify whether the users have logged into another system. Until the API gets updated (hopefully soon) each user requires a separate request, which is why I'm batching them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Drupal Queue](http://drupal.org/project/drupal_queue) is a backport of Drupal 7's queue API for Drupal 6. It provides basically the same features as [Job Queue](http://drupal.org/project/job_queue). However a big advantage with Drupal Queue is that it uses the same API as Drupal 7 Core. This means if your module uses Drupal Queue in D6, your upgrade path to 7 will be effortless.

Answer (score 0):

Another module to consider is [PubSub](http://drupal.org/project/pubsub).

Unfortunately I have only used PubSub before, not the others, so I can't compare them.  If I were coding this, my first attempt would be to "publish" the users and have a drush command that would run periodically that would "subscribe" and handle them in batches.